# MVC3 IPolicyViolationHandler "Access Denied!" Popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an mvc3 app which uses FluentSecurity in which policy violation is handled with  IPolicyViolationHandler

public class DefaultPolicyViolationHandler : IPolicyViolationHandler
{
    public string ViewName = "AccessDenied";

```
public ActionResult Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)
{

    if (SecurityHelper.UserIsAuthenticated())
    {

        return new ViewResult { ViewName = ViewName };
    }
    else
    {
        return new RedirectResult(LoginURL);
    }
}
```

}

now it opens a new page with my Shared View AccessDenied. My question is how can i open a popup instead of a new page to show the "Access Denied msg". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead RedirectResult you can return PartialView with model like bellow.

In Your Controller .....

```
Model.Test M = new Model.Test();
M.Access = "Denied";
return PartialView("ViewName",M);
```

In your View......

```
 @model eStorage.Models.Test

 <input type="hidden" id="hdnAccess" value ="@Model.Access" />

<script>
  var Type = $("#hdnAccess").val();
  if(Type == "Denied")
  {
    //window.open    code here
    // or  
    // Use Jquery Dialog
   }

 </script>
```